# How to retrieve the column name from the db

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to execute the column names from a MySQL database using Flask. I have created UI for this, user has to enter their username and password as well as data such as the port, dbname, etc. The connection to the database has been established successfully.

- I need to retrieve the column name from the db

My cursor.execute is below

```
cursor.execute("select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME= '%s'" %(i))
```

My output

```
{'Employee': ['COLUMN_NAME'], 'Department': ['COLUMN_NAME']}
```

Expected Out

```
| COLUMN_NAME  |
+--------------+
| emp_no       |
| emp_name     |
| age          |
```

while i done manually execute from mysql `select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='employee';` i got the proper out

Using python version 3

```
@app.route('/connections',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def db_connections():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dbtype = request.form.get('dbtype');
        dbuser = request.form.get('dbuser');
        dbpw = request.form.get('dbpw');
        hname = request.form.get('hname');
        hport = request.form.get('hport');
        dbname = request.form.get('dbname');
        if(dbtype == "MYSQL"):
            try:
                connection = mysql.connector.connect(user = dbuser,
                                  password = dbpw,
                                  host = hname,
                                  port = hport,
                                  database = dbname)
                cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
            except (Exception) as error :
                print ("Error while connecting to SQL", error)
        def get_table_col_names(table_str):
            for i in table_str:
                    cursor.execute("select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME= '%s'" %(i))
                    col_names = []
                    for desc in cursor.description:
                        col_names.append(desc[0])        
                        all_databaselists[i] = col_names               
            return all_databaselists 
        cursor.execute("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'base table' AND table_schema='test'")
        records = cursor.fetchall() 
        print (records)
        result = [i[0] for i in records]     
        all_columns = get_table_col_names(result)
        print (all_columns)
        cursor.close()           
   return render_template('connections.html')
```

Comment: What do you mean you're trying to get the column names using Flask? Flask is just a python web framework and does not natively support databases. It looks to me that you're using sqlite3 db-api or MySQLdb interface; could you confirm how it is you're connecting to the database in python?

Comment: @ev350, i have created UI using FLASK, my agenda is mysql table has to appear in the UI ones Table appear there should columns to appear, so to see column we need to the `cursor.execute("select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME= '%s'" %(i))
` , the above query is working in mysql shell while doing with python + Mysql its not showing

Comment: Yes, but which module are you using to connect to your database?

Comment: @ev350 mysql.connector

Comment: which version of python? And can you show us the code you use to print out the result from the cursor?

Comment: Also, what is the value of (i) that you replace in your query string?

Comment: @ev350 posted the code for connection

Comment: `create table employee
(
 emp_no integer,
 emp_name varchar(20),
 age integer
);

insert into students values (1, 'Michael', 19);
insert into students values (2, 'Doug', 18);
insert into students values (3, 'Samantha', 21);

create table courses
(
 course_no varchar(5),
 course_title varchar(20),
 credits integer
);

insert into courses values ('CS110', 'Pre Calculus', 4);
insert into courses values ('CS180', 'Physics', 4);
insert into courses values ('CS107', 'Intro to Psychology', 3);
`

Comment: @eve350 above is sample two tables 'employees' and 'courses '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you were looking at the descriptions from the cursor rather than looking at the results returned from the query that you executed. The code I've attached below should work for you - it returns a dictionary of table names with the associated column names as lists.

```
def get_table_col_names(table_str):
    all_databaselists = {}
    for i in table_str:
        cursor.execute(
            "select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME= '%s'" % (i))
        tableDesc = cursor.fetchall()
        col_names = []
        for desc in tableDesc:
            col_names.append(desc[0])
            all_databaselists[i] = col_names
    return all_databaselists

cursor.execute("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema='test'")
records = cursor.fetchall() 
result = [i[0] for i in records]     
all_columns = get_table_col_names(result)
print (all_columns)
cursor.close()
```

**Note:** I changed `'base table'` to `'BASE TABLE'` as this how the string for the table_type was represented in my database.

**Tested:**

I created the following table:

```
mysql> describe employee;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no   | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| emp_name | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| age      | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The script provided above gives the following output:

```
{'employee': ['age', 'emp_name', 'emp_no']}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, `{'employee': ['employee_no']}` only its coming expected is  `{'employee': ['empe_no', 'emp_name',age]}` and also expecting whatever tables are there it has to retrieve all the tables

Comment: @Nons I don't know what you're trying to say here. Could you try formulate it as a question perhaps? Thanks

Comment: basically with your code we need to retrieve the columns of what evertable like {'employee': ['empe_no', 'emp_name',age]} , employee is the table name and 'empe_no', 'emp_name',age are the column names

Comment: with your code {'employee': ['empe_no']} is only coming

Comment: @Nons I edited my answer to give the results I got. Please double check that you're applying it to the correct database perhaps? Thanks for the green tick :)

Comment: i got it, `    def get_table_col_names(table_str):
        all_databaselists = {}
        for i in table_str:
            cursor.execute("select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME= '%s'" % (i))
            tableDesc1 = cursor.fetchall()
            print ('tableDesc1', tableDesc1)
            tableDesc = [i[0] for i in tableDesc1]
            print (tableDesc)
            all_databaselists[i] = tableDesc
        return all_databaselists`   Thank you so much you are awesome

Comment: `cursor.execute("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema='test'")
    candidate_records = cursor.fetchall() 
    print (candidate_records)
        #res = [''.join(i) for i in candidate_records]
    res = [i[0] for i in candidate_records]
        
    all_cols = get_table_col_names(res)
    print ('all colu',all_cols)`